# Nunjucks helper functions

Tags: handlebars.js, nunjucks

I'm creating HTML using Mozilla's Nunjucks template parsing engine. I used Handlebars in the past and I'm looking for the Nunjucks way to do Handlebars helpers (normal functions written in Javascript that can be called and passed data for transformation in the template).

My current usecase is that I get a date in sortable ISO 8601 format `yyyy-mm-dd` like `2018-03-12`, and I need to transform that to the German standard date format `dd.mm.yyyy` (`12.03.2018`) for displaying.

As of now I'm doing this in my template using

```
{{ date.split('-').reverse().join('.') }}
```

Now when I have alot of dates that need formatting, or even if I want to do preference-specific formatting, I#d love to pass `date` to a helper function `formatDate` that does the conversion for me:

File: `./helper/functions.njk`

```
{% set
  formatDate = function(date) {
    if (typeof date !== 'string') {
      return date
    } else {
      return date.split('-').reverse().join('.')
    }
  }
%}
```

which I would then like to use in my page template like

```
{{ formatDate(date) }}
```

For this simple use case a filter would also work:

```
{{ date | formatDate }}
```

But it seems you cannot define functions like this in Nunjucks:

```
[Compile Error] expected block end in set statement
```

Is there anything I'm missing or is Nunjucks simply less powerful than Handlebars in this regard?

The usecase here is simple, but another usecase for these helper functions would be e.g. to extract a unique list of cities from a job offer list which you can then iterate over and create a dropdown that has a alphabetic list of cities where jobs are offered.

Comment: Check `addGlobal` and `addFilter` API.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to include this in my general Nunjucks config, I would like to have this on a per-import basis. As far as I've dived into the matter, it seems this is not available in Nunjucks - on the other hand Handlebars helpers need to be globally registered via the config as well, so it's no different.

Answer (score 0):

Nunjucks parse all code in `{{ }}` and `{% %}` brackets, so you can't use js-code inside template. Most function such as `typeof` must be declare by `addGlobal` before use it. I use `date.split and ...` to "check" that date is a `string`.

```
// helpers.njk
{% macro formatDate(date) %}
{{ date.split and date.split('-').reverse().join('.') or date }}
{% endmacro %}
... // another macros

// usage
{% import 'helpers.njk' as helpers %}
{{ helpers.formatDate('2018-03-12') }}
```